# Question about law of substitution in stochastic integral

Tags: integration, stochastic-integrals

I need to compute some Integrals for my stochastic course. And i have the following problem:

$$ \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{\lambda}{y}) \frac{1}{y^n} dy = \star$$
so i substitute $x = \frac{1}{y}, \; dy = -\frac{dx}{x^2} $.
$$\star =- \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\lambda x) x^{(n-1)-1} dy = -\frac{\lambda}{n-1}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)} \exp(-\lambda x) x^{(n-1)-1} dy = -\frac{\lambda}{n-1} $$
By the definition of the gamma distriution. But it should be $\frac{\lambda}{n-1}$.
I ask myself where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i forgot to change the boundaries, so we have:
$$ \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{\lambda}{y}) \frac{1}{y^n} dy = \star$$
so i substitute $x = \frac{1}{y}, \; dy = -\frac{dx}{x^2} $ and $\phi(y) = \frac{1}{y}$, so $\phi(\infty) = 0, \; \phi(0) = \infty$.
$$\star =- \frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)} \int_\infty^{0} \exp(-\lambda x) x^{(n-1)-1} dy = \frac{\lambda}{n-1}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)} \exp(-\lambda x) x^{(n-1)-1} dy = \frac{\lambda}{n-1} $$